# Cakephp routing without subdirectory name

Tags: cakephp

I am working on a CakePHP application. When I uploaded it to my host's public_html directory I have created a subdirectory for it.

So right now the structure is like that: domain.com/subdircake/.

I have included a .htaccess file in the public_html root, and I have changed the index.php in the webroot folder to point the subdirectory.

I don't know if it is a routing issue inside the cakeapp or a mod_rewrite issue because of a wrong .htaccess configuration, but what happens is this.

1. I can access the domain and it shows the home page for the app.
2. The links are pointing to domain.com/subdircake/action instead of domain.com/action.
3. When I am forcing the url to be domain.com/action it works and this leaves me stressed because I don't know why.

So I think it has to be some rewrite issue but I don't have any clues.

Anyone any idea?

Comment: Is another website already hosted in that public_html directory? Do you also have access to the directories 'outside' the public_html directory? Just to inform what options would apply to you.

Comment: Nope, this is the only site. I don't have access outside the public_html directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why going to `domain.com/action` works is that your .htaccess solution was effective - it is indeed rewriting the URL to the right location. However, CakePHP's routing system is unaware of the changes you made to the default rewriting script, which causes the HTML Helper to generate links that still point to the place they would without you editing the .htaccess file.

The first solution that comes to mind is changing your `App.base` configuration; in `Config/bootstrap.php`, add this line:

`Configure::write('App.base','/');`

And see if that helps. I would recommend testing the site thoroughly after changing that setting, though - many CakePHP features use it, and the results could be unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use userdir mod ?

If you do so, you have to edit the 3 cake .htaccess (located in the root of your cake folder, in your app/ folder and in your app/webroot/ folder, and add one of these line just after the `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
#.htaccess :
RewriteBase /~username/

#app/.htaccess :
RewriteBase /~username/app

#app/webroot/.htaccess :
RewriteBase /~username/app/webroot
```

Replace username by your username, but don't forget the ~

If you cake folder is in a subdir, it will be `/~username/subdir/...`

Answer (score 0):

Put the contents of the `webroot` directory in your `public_html` folder.

Then change `index.php` (in webroot/public_html, not in cake's app dir) the following lines

```
if (!defined('ROOT')) {
    define('ROOT', 'subcakedir');
}

/**
 * The actual directory name for the "app".
 *
 */
if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
    define('APP_DIR', 'app');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Thiago Campezzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/708395/thiago-campezzi)'s answer works perfectly, I had exact same problem with [Kornel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/754859/kornel)

In `Config/bootstrap.php`, add this line:

```
Configure::write('App.base','/');
```

I can't comment or vote yet so I wrote it here :) Thank you!! I search'd hours for this answer!

And by the way, this works with .htaccess and without it, so no need to change this every time you upload new version of app to web server.

Comment: Please do not add "thank you" answers. For useful answers, just vote them up once you have the rep.